# running grunt task as configuration in webstorm

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm

In webstorm, running `grunt serve` from the terminal works flawlessly and presents me with a webpage. However, when I make a configuration and run that, there's an error concerning SASS to CSS compilation:

```
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Warning: Running "compass:server" (compass) task
Warning: You need to have Ruby and Compass installed and in your system PATH for this task to work. More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

which I do not understand, as I'm using the same settings (described [here](http://youtu.be/_HYVuHHR55A?t=10m9s))

Comment: 1) IDE version? 2) Your OS? 3) How do you launch IDE -- from shortcut (clicking on icon) or from terminal/console? Right now it looks like IDE does not see proper/full `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Right. 1) Newest, 9.0.1, but it was present in previous versions too 2) Linux Ubuntu. 3) Clicking on icon in launcher bar. Using the Grunt console (docked at bottom) has the same problem of getting stuck on the `compass:server` task

Ah, so the terminal console is just a 'real' docked terminal window, unaffected by the IDE not seeing the `PATH`. That makes sense. 

**Wow, starting Webstorm from the terminal eliminates the problem!**

Anyone any idea why and how to make it work when starting it from shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Seems WebStorm doesn't see your terminal environment when being started from shortcut. Pleasee try editing the launcher as suggested in https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5513463#5513463 - does it help?

Comment: I can confirm that running `./webstorm.sh` from the terminal (from the `bin` directory of the webstorm folder) resolves the issue. But running `/bin/bash -l -c "/home/elrudi/Software/Webstorm/WebStorm-139.252/bin/webstorm.sh"` from the terminal does not solve the issue. 
Likewise, changing the line `Exec="/home/elrudi/Software/Webstorm/WebStorm-139.252/bin/webstorm.sh" %f` in the `.desktop` file to `Exec=/bin/bash -l -c "/home/elrudi/Software/Webstorm/WebStorm-139.252/bin/webstorm.sh"` does not resolve the issue for the launcher.